# touchmove prevent default/signature capture doesnt work on a windows tablet

Tags: jquery, html, tablet, tablet-pc

i have a windows tablet here and am working on signature capture for a web app.

on an ipad and droid you can use

```
$("body").on('touchmove', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

to lock the page in place as you sign. this isnt working on the windows tablet. any ideas?

*just found out that it works in many scenarios by pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> for full screen. it would still be nice to have a non full screen solution.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does not implement the proprietary Apple touch events. You will need to bind to MSPointerMove as well.

See [Touch Input for IE10 and Metro style Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/20/touch-input-for-ie10-and-metro-style-apps.aspx) for further information as well as examples.